# Shopify - Change text of my selectorOption product dropdown variant

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, shopify, liquid

I worked all day on it and impossible to figure it out so I need some help :)

I try to add some text on each variant line of my "Size" dropdown on my product page :

if the product quantity > 0 : Size + Quick Delivery
else : Size + 2-3 weeks delivery
Just want to display it to the customer before the click, so I don't want it just on the selectedVariant.

I tried to change it by my script.js, I was thinking to :

copy each variant quantity (I didn't find the way to do it)

copy my Dropdown in a list value/key + add text (Quick/2-3 weeks) depending of the variant quantity
var optionsSizes = {};

```js
var optionsSizes = {};

$('#mySizes option').each(function(){
    optionsSizes[$(this).val()] = $(this).text() + variant.inventory_quantity;
});

//console.log(optionsSizes);    
    
var $el = $("#mySizes");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$.each(optionsSizes, function(value,key) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

The copy/paste of the dropdown work but that's all.
It was easy to do it on variantSelected but that's not what I want.

Please feel free to ask if you have any question.

Cheers,

bkseen

Comment: Is `variant.inventory_quantity` from liquid or is there a JSON object called variant?

Comment: I think variant.inventory_quantity is from liquid

Comment: Ah.. You can't combine JS and liquid like that. Provide a link to the page, let me see what needs to be done there.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. 
Link : https://www.loakeshoes.com.au/collections/all-product-available/products/loakegunny?variant=18977095815 

For instance the size 10.5 is available and the size 7 is not (click on them to see the difference), so I would like to display front of each variant a text ("quick delivery / 2-3 weeks delivery") depends of the stock.

As there : http://www.loake.co.uk/shoe-care/belts/henry.html if you choose black, for the dropdown Size you have some <option> with "due on 16/05/16". That's totally what I would like to display. :)

Comment: That's tricky but I think I can help. How are you changing the `span` with the classes `product__inventory-count product__form-message--success` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('#product-select-5916642311-option-0')` and `$('#mySizes')` this `select` elements are not in your theme by default. A Shopify or theme script adds these two elements based on the product's JSON information available via Shopify. Hence there is no direct way to get the desired result.

Here's the trick that can achieve what you desire.

1. Load all the variants and their required properties into a JSON object. To do this add `<script>variantsJSON = {}</script>` at the top of the liquid file.
2. Now load the variants in the following structure:

   `variantsJSON = {
       "variant_option1" : {
           "variant_option2_1_title" : "variant_option2_1_quantity",
           "variant_option2_2_title" : "variant_option2_2_quantity",
       } ....
   }`
3. To get the above structure, you need to add the following script inside `{% for variant in product.variants %}` or a similar loop in your liquid file.

`<script>
    if (!variantsJSON['{{ variant.option1 }}']){
        variantsJSON['{{ variant.option1 }}'] = {}
    }
    {% assign availability = 'QUICK DELIVERY' %}
    {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}{% assign availability = '2-3 WEEKS DELIVERY' %}{% endif %}
    if (!variantsJSON['{{ variant.option1 }}']['{{ variant.option2 }}']){
        variantsJSON['{{ variant.option1 }}']['{{ variant.option2 }}'] = '{{ availability }}'
    }
</script>`

4. The above snippet (possible refinement required) will load all the variants and their availability into the JSON object
5. Now all you need to do is trigger a function on change of `$('#product-select-{{ product.id }}-option-0')` which will clear all `<li>`s in `$('#mySizes')`, then populates them using the values stored in **variantsJSON**'s **variant_option2** & **variant_availability** of the selected **variant_option1**

*P.S. Feel free to format my answer. I'm somehow unable to get the right formatting.*

Comment: They removed my answers -_- Annoying rules but anyway,

Thanks @HymnZ, I could create my 2 objects into my Javascript variant for the selected item because of you (I'm not sure that it's going to work for the quick shop because I stop the list to the first product [just to have the product selected] , but anyway I will fix it later) :)

I've created an image to display you my result and my script. Unfortunately I don't know how to access the childs of my objects, get the value etc..

Comment: I just success to modify the dropdown box text but I have to read my 2 lists now to check availability and display a variable text : "Quick delivery" or "2-3 weeks". I've never been so close so your solution seems the good one finally ^^

<a href="http://i.stack.imgur.com/UZEcS.jpg"> Script.js + Console
 </a>

Comment: Ok. I notice a flaw in my code above and I've changed it. To get the correct results inside '#mySizes option' loop do this: `$(this).text($(this).val()+' '+variantsJSON[$('select[data-option="option1"]').val()][$(this).val()]+' delivery')`

Comment: I couldn't put in place your "new solution".. :*(

First of all I had to add ' ' between {{ variant_option2 }} otherwise an error occurred. After, it return me just 1 option2 per option1 so I think that's not the good one.

I think the first solution was the good one, I just need to know how to access in my console the childs

Object {leather-black: Object, leather-test: Object}
leather-black
:
Object
variant_availability
:
Array[6]
0
:
"3"
1
:
"4"

Comment: @bkseen.. Apologies. I had mistyped syntax in the new code, I have corrected it. I'd prefer you use the new code as it is easy to access the object data. I've attached the screenshot of how to get the access with details - `http://s32.postimg.org/6qn72m4zp/v_JSON.jpg`; I hope this helps. Alternatively, I can help you debug further if I can access `variantsJSON` in the link you mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot HymnZ, I found another solution with the first one !! :) I will post it tommorow afternoon if I have time, crazy busy at work.

I will try your other solution next week!

Cheers and thanks again

Comment: Finally I checked the side effects (with the functionality "quick shop" or other featured product) and it doesn't work.
I published my copy of the website it will be easier for you to check : https://anatomicshoes.myshopify.com/collections/catalogue/products/anatomiccobayman?variant=17792358337
So, I don't know how to get dynamically the product ID to search on my list variantsJSON the good one by ID.
By the way on my Script.js I couldn't find the way to do my $('#product-select-{{ product.id }}-option-0').on('change', function() {... myFunctin });
Where I have to put that? Thanks again ;)

Comment: 'Quick Shop' and other popup features can also be done. I saw your code. Right now, I see that `leather-black` is not working properly (or is it?) Since it is a copy, I'd still request you to populate your `variantsJSON` using the new way. It'll be less complicated code and less browser RAM eating, I can promise you this.

Comment: I tried your new solution but it didn't work good as I have a loop on my product_form.liquid because there is some related products / collection. Whatever, it seems populate my JSON list but I couldn't have something dynamic with my script.js, a bit lost my brain is going to burn with that feature!

Comment: I can tell you this as I have done the same thing for my page. All you need to do is to load all "Size"s into an "Material-Colour" specific arrays when page loads. `optionSelector` does this but not pretty and you don't have an access to that data. For each "Size" now there should a characteristic (availability) mapped. Easiest way is JSON. `'Material-Colour' : { 'size_x' : 'size_x's_availability' }`. When Material-Colour is changed all you need to do is call `Material-Color['size_x']` and it'll return `'size_x's_availability'`. You can then put this inside `$('#mySizes option')` function.

Answer (score 0):

To answer Hymnz on

> That's tricky but I think I can help. How are you changing the span with the classes product__inventory-count product__form-message--success ? – HymnZ 10 hours ago
>   Blockquote

```
if (variant) {
  {% if settings.product_show_shipping %}
    var myCount = variant['inventory_quantity'];
    var myPath = this.element.find('.product__inventory-count');
        if (myCount < 1){
            myPath.removeClass('product__form-message--success');
            myPath.addClass('product__form-message--error');
            myPath.text("2-3 weeks delivery");
        }else{
            //myPath.toggleClass('product__form-message--success').siblings().removeClass('checked');
            myPath.removeClass('product__form-message--error');
            myPath.addClass('product__form-message--success');
            myPath.text("Quick delivery");
        }
  {% endif %}
```

The thing is, variant is the variant selected and not going through all the product's variants.